# Accessing Linux kernel structure memblock from my kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I am using the Linux-5.11.1 and
I am trying to figure out if there is an opportunity to get the pointer to the memblock structure in my module. I know that if the CONFIG_ARCH_KEEP_MEMBLOCK is not set the all information about this structure will be disappeared after kernel initialization. I have recompiled the kernel and now trying to get the pointer on this structure but there are no special methods that will provide me with this opportunity, so I am going to write my own in this way:

```
void* get_memblock(void){
    return &memblock;
}

EXPORT_SYMBOL(get_memblock)
```

Is this the right way to overcome my problem?

Comment: Why not just `extern struct memblock memblock;` the same way memblock.h does it?  Or just, `#include "memblock.h"`?

Comment: I have tried, but there is one problem with your suggestion. My module compiles in userspace, so it means that the linker can not find this structure(not definition). And this is the reason why I use EXPORT_SYMBOL(). If I clearly understand, it works this way.

Comment: You can't access kernel memory from userspace, nor can you call kernel functions.  Your call is only useful to a kernel module.